# How to add attribute values to the footer in Magento, as a list?

Tags: magento, attributes, footer, advanced-search

My products in Magento have attribute Brand. What I need to do is to display a list of Brands in the footer.Something like: Our Brands: Brand 1, Brand 2, Brand 3...

As far as I understand I need somehow retrieve values from Advanced search and display them in footer as a list, but I don't know how to do it. Does anybody have solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several steps to follow

here i am giving detail instruction how to add your custom attribute at footer.

**1.** you have to create on block to get all your brand product with assign your custom attribute

for block.

```
$attributes = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY) // pass your attribute id
    ->getAttributeCollection()
    ->addSetInfo();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
{
    if ($attribute->usesSource())
    {
        echo "{$attribute->getFrontendLabel()}:\n";
        foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions() as $option)
        {
            echo "  {$option['label']}\n";
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

above is print logic you should have to store it one array in return with one variable.

**2.** create view file in your theme for display purpose and call that block function in that home_logo file.

```
<?php $_brandsCollection = $this->getBrandsLogoCollection();?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav">
<div class="block-title">
    <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Brands') ?></span></strong>
</div>
 <div class="block-content" > 
          <div id="Carousel2" class="carousel">
                <div class="button navButton previous" style="display:none;">Back</div>
                <div class="button navButton next" style="display:none;">More</div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="items">
                    <?php foreach ($_brandsCollection as $_brand): ?>                    
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="key caption"></div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                                        <img class="brand-base-logo" alt="<?php echo $_brand->getBrandLogo() ?>" src="<?php echo $_brand->getBrandLogo(); ?>" width="50" height="50">            
                            </div>                    
                            <div class="picture">
                            </div>
                        </div>                            
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end block content-->            
</div>
```

**3.** Assign that file to footer using your_layout.xml with reference before footer.

```
<reference name="footer">
       <block type="brand/left" name="brands_logolist" before="-" template="brand/home_logo.phtml" />
  </reference>
```

Hope you can understand my logic.

Comment: Hi, Liyakat! Thank you for your answer, but it's not exactly what I want. I don't want the products to appear in footer and I don't have logos for my brands. What I want is to display "products attribute - brand". I already have it in Advanced search as multiselect. All I need is this values from Advanced search to be displayed in footer as list.

Comment: I need not the result of a search (not the products), but the brands names, so that user could click on brand name, and it will take him to the page with all products that have this brand attribute.

Comment: yes just try with above block and you will get brand name in controller just debug that

Comment: @Artur Klassen, glad to help you. will you pls vote my answer so some one can trust and utilize if for future reference.